# Sendmail ZF2 spaces stripped out of subject

Tags: php, php-5.3, sendmail, zend-framework2

I just created a mailer class for Zend Framework 2. It uses the Sendmail class.

The problem is that I set the subject of the email with multiple words. Before sending I dump the subject and all the spaces are ok. After sending the email I check my gmail and all the spaces are stripped out of the subject.

When I run the script I get "testemail" as the subject.

Below a part of the class I created :

```
public function addFile($p_sPath, $p_sMimetype, $p_sFilename){
    $rFile = fopen($p_sPath,'rb');
    $this->_m_oAttachment = new Mimepart(fread($rFile,filesize($p_sPath)));
    $this->_m_oAttachment->type = $p_sMimetype;
    $this->_m_oAttachment->filename = $p_sFilename;
    $this->_m_oAttachment->disposition = 'attachment';
    $this->_m_oAttachment->encoding = Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
}


public function sendEmail()
{
    $aParts = (!is_null($this->_m_oAttachment)) 
            ? array($this->_m_oBodymessage, $this->_m_oAttachment) 
            : array($this->_m_oBodymessage);

    $this->_m_oBodypart->setParts($aParts);

    $this->_m_oMessage->setEncoding('utf-8')
                      ->setBody($this->_m_oBodypart)
                      ->addFrom($this->_fromAddress, $this->_fromName)
                      ->addReplyTo($this->_fromAddress, $this->_fromName)
                      ->setSubject($this->_subject);
                      // even here the spaces are still intact.
    $this->send($this->_m_oMessage);
}



$oMailer = $this->getLocator()->get('Core\Mailer');
$oMailer->setBodyHtml('mail/mail.phtml', array('aData' => $aData));
$oMailer->setSubject('test email');
$oMailer->setRecipient('jacob@myemail.com', 'jacob');
$oMailer->addFile(realpath(dirname(__file__). '/../../../../../'.$sPath.$sSubfolder.'/'.$sFilename), 'application/pdf', $aData['data']['eventID'].'_'.$aDeclaratie['data']['userID'].'.pdf');
$oMailer->sendEmail();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed with Zend Framework 2 stable

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-258